# Only show matched weekdays

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index i have a field called available_weekdays. It's an array with weekdays from 1-7.

In my query i pass a start_date with the format `'yyyy-MM-dd'`.

**Goal:**
I only want to show records which match the start_date weekday.

Lets say i pass 2017-01-01 to my query which is weekday 7. My query would have to convert my passed date to a weekday. Then it checks for a matching weekday in the available_weekdays field. If weekday is found in available_weekdays return the record.

ES version: 2.4.4

Is this possible by using a script filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-script-query.html)

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":{
        "script":{
          "script":{
            "lang":"groovy",
            "inline":"doc['available_weekdays'].values.find{it == DateTime.parse(param1).dayOfWeek().get()}",
            "params":{
              "param1":"2017-01-01"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, something was off with my answer. +1 for you !

Comment: hm this is weird - it doesn't return any records.. i do have records with available_weekdays = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] so it should match. there's no error returned. i can't find any documentation on the DateTime class just for Date. maybe i have to specify the date format somehow? groovy scripting works - just tried to match non empty available_weekdays. thanks!

Comment: Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '2017-12-04')[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] puts out the right integer in groovy console but doesn't work in es.

Comment: Something should be wrong with your test data. Try mine: `https://justpaste.it/1e4e1`.  
DateTime is JodaTime class `http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html`
It parses the format you use even without specifying the format

Comment: @TarasKohut if i use exactly your testdata the query returns all 3 records. 2017-01-01 should be sunday. so depending on the dayOfWeek() output sunday should either be 1 or 7. so it should only return one record - right?

Comment: @TarasKohut aah you searched with GET in your example. if i use POST it works! amazing thanks a lot!

Comment: That's right, my example is a little bit confusing, because I use sense chrome plugin, it automatically changes GET to POST when it's needed.